# Document generated with PHP does not show preview in OSX

Tags: php, macos, file

I've just generated a whole bunch of XML documents using file_put_contents(). This is what the call looks like:

```
    file_put_contents('~output/organisations/xml/org'.$org->orgNr.'.xml', $xml);
```

However, when I navigate to one of those documents in Finder (in OSX Mavericks), it doesn't generate a document preview. According to Get Info it is a valid XML document. 
When I compare Get Info of another, already existing, XML document (that wasn't generated by my script) the existing XML document has a document preview, but my generated document does not.

See screenshots below:

[image: Get Info for the existing XML document]

[image: Get Info for generated XML document]

Can anyone tell me why this is? Should I have passed more information to file_put_contents()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: file_put_contents() is not the appropriate function to use to generate an XML document.
An instance of SimpleXMLElement must be created instead.

This is how:

```
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$xmlobj->asXML('filename.xml');
```

This is also helpful because PHP will throw Exceptions if your XML isn't valid, so if say one of your open/end tags doesn't match you'll know.